# padding data in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I have a txt file with the following data:

```
43,70,90,12,98,54,23
80,100,21,67
23,45
30
```

I want to do the padding on the data so that the data will have the same length, eg I want to do with the number 0 padding so that the output should be:

```
43,70,90,12,98,54,23
80,100,21,67,0,0,0
23,45,0,0,0,0,0
30,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

What would be the best way to do this in Python?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Is the top row always the longest length and complete?

Comment: The longest data is not always located on the top line, they may be random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Determine the maximum number of columns that your text/file has
2. Append additional columns to the lines that do not have the maximum number

Sample code for reading from text file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

output = ""
with open("1.txt") as f:
    # Determine number of columns
    cols = max([len(line.split(",")) for line in f])
    print("Maximum number of columns: %d" % cols)

    # Build output string, starting from beginning of file
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        output += line.strip() + ",0" * (cols - len(line.split(","))) + "\n"
print("Output:", output)
```

Sample code for reading from string literal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# You could read text from file. Here we use a literal string
text = """43,70,90,12,98,54,23
80,100,21,67
23,45
30
"""

# Split text to lines
lines = text.splitlines(False)

# Determine number of columns
cols = max([len(line.split(",")) for line in lines])
print("Maximum number of columns: %d" % cols)

output = ""
for line in lines:
    output += line + ",0" * (cols - len(line.split(","))) + "\n"

print("Output:", output)
```

Both examples use list comprehensions.

To learn more about how they work, read the following:

> - [Python Documentation - 5.1.4. List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps)
> - [Python: List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

input_list = []  # list to keep track of input
max_number_of_columns = 0  # maximum number of columns
number_of_rows = 0

with open("test.txt") as testfile:
    for line in testfile:
        # read line, strip end of line and split at the comma
        line = line.replace("\n", "") 
        values = line.split(",")

        number_of_rows += 1
        if len(values) > max_number_of_columns:
            max_number_of_columns = len(values)
        print values
        input_list.append(values)  # add new values to the list
# initialize all zero numpy array
np_array = np.zeros((number_of_rows, max_number_of_columns))
for i, row in enumerate(input_list):
    np_array[i,:len(row)] = row  # write entries into the array
```